# Execution Plan Warnings cardinality xml data type

Tags: sql-server, optimization, execution-plan, plan-cache, warning

I have the following statements:

```
-- 1st
DECLARE @AuditParameters XML = (
    SELECT
        1 AS AccountID,
        2 AS CategoryID,
        3 AS CategoryAttributeID,
        '4' AS SyncBatchGUID
    FOR XML PATH(N'Parameters'), ELEMENTS XSINIL
)
```

-

```
-- 2nd
DECLARE @AuditParameters XML = convert(xml, (
    SELECT
        1 AS AccountID,
        2 AS CategoryID,
        3 AS CategoryAttributeID,
        '4' AS SyncBatchGUID
    FOR XML PATH(N'Parameters'), ELEMENTS XSINIL
))
```

Both statements result in the same execution plan, however, they display the warning message

> Type conversion in expression (CONVERT_IMPLICIT(xml,[Expr1004],0))
>   may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice.

You may note I have tried to convert the second statement to XML and yet I get the same warning message.

**How can I get rid of this warning message on the statement above?**

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [TYPE Directive in FOR XML Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/type-directive-in-for-xml-queries?view=sql-server-ver15)

> SQL Server support for the [xml (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-transact-sql) enables you to optionally request that the result of a FOR XML query be returned as xml data type by specifying the TYPE directive.

```
-- 1st
DECLARE @AuditParameters XML = (
    SELECT
        1 AS AccountID,
        2 AS CategoryID,
        3 AS CategoryAttributeID,
        '4' AS SyncBatchGUID
    FOR XML PATH(N'Parameters'), ELEMENTS XSINIL,Type
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `TYPE` to return `XML` from the inner query rather than a string

```
DECLARE @AuditParameters XML = (
    SELECT
        1 AS AccountID,
        2 AS CategoryID,
        3 AS CategoryAttributeID,
        '4' AS SyncBatchGUID
    FOR XML PATH(N'Parameters'), ELEMENTS XSINIL, TYPE
)
```